# classes that reference each other code design

Tags: c++

I have a class that is fairly large and i want to split key parts but i don't know if my code design is preferred

```
 class Something
{
public:
    void draw()
    {
        m_drawer.draw();
    }

private:
    SomethingDrawer m_drawer;
}

class SomethingDrawer
{
public:
    SomethingDrawer(Something* something) :
        m_something(something)
    {}

    void draw()
    {
        drawSomethingObject();
        drawSomeOtherObject();
    }

private:
    void drawSomethingObject();
    void drawSomeOtherObject();

    Something* m_something;
}
```

Or should i just pass the Something objects needed for drawing to `drawSomethingObject/drawSomeOtherObject` without SomethingDrawer needing a reference to Something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the "preferred" method is something of a matter of opinion and may depend on the details of what you are trying to achieve, the [single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) suggests that it may be better not to wrap your drawer as an instance attribute and instead pass your "Something" objects to a "Drawer" as needed. If the responsibility of a "Something" is to hold data about something, then there is no need to give it the additional responsibility of rendering that data in some form.

In fact, the [Model-View-Controller (MVC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) design pattern takes advantage of exactly this distinction. If "Something" holds your data (is the model) and you later decide that you want multiple ways of "drawing" (viewing) that data, then avoiding the coupling between the drawing and data-holding classes will give you greater flexibility.

One other thing worth considering here is that unless the drawer needs to hold onto state specific to the "Something" data (which would already be a bit of a code smell), you can probably just create one drawer and pass it "Somethings" as needed rather than creating one for each Something instance.